# How long does cooked TVP keep in the fridge?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, soy

How long can I keep cooked [textured vegetable protein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textured_vegetable_protein) (soy) in fridge and does it matter if it is mixed with for example some spices and rice? Will it then shorten the duration of how long it's good to eat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long term storage of TVP once it has been cooked, I prefer to bake it into crumbles so that the moisture is reduced (and it adds to the toothsomeness of it) before storage. To bake it into crumbles, just lay out in small meatball-style heaps on parchment and bake until dried through.

This is beneficial in both freezer (yes, it freezes very well and reheats in about the same time as when refrigerated) and refrigerator storage as the moisture will burn in the freezer and turn the TVP texture grainy, and in the fridge it can soak up some stray smells easily.

When wet, I find that storing it for between 3-5 days doesn't make it too soggy and limp when reheating, for longer than that I find it preferable to freeze not for the sake of contamination but because it preserves the texture better and the flavor and takes up less fridge space.

Answer (score 1):

I've kept mine in the fridge (unmixed with other things) for over a week without any issues. I'd say it's probably safe to keep slightly longer than meat because it doesn't have the same levels of naturally occurring bacteria.